# Why facebook APP Review team cant access our web-application during review?

Tags: facebook, review

During the app review, the Facebook team is open our website https://jivochat.com and then should log into web-application: https://app.jivosite.com, but they faced with ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR problem. This is a strange situation as we have more than 250 000 customers around the world without any problems. We are using goDaddy (OV) SSL Certificate for our web-application: https://app.jivosite.com

As it is a problem on app review team side, we don't know what we should do to fix this issue. Is there any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Hi, how did you solve? We've encountered the same problem! Thanks

Comment: They have some problem with GoDaddy certificate on our site, so we provide them another domain to log into our website (from another region)